# Is it possible to open Windows File Explorer by using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-management

I have an app with Frontend on React(TypeScript) and Backend on .NET 6.0

It creates Excel file and downloads it on Desktop version, but it's kept in App source folder.
I want to move it from source folder to more User-friendly (let's say: C://User/userX/Documents)
So after creation on Web version there's download button but on Desktop it should allow user to open File Explorer where file is kept after creation.

I've seen some file explorer npm packages but none of them worked for me.

Comment: How are you building the Desktop version? React is a browser-based framework, so are you using something like Electron or...?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder User doesn't chose where to keep it, it's automatically processed based on informations he provides before creation begins, after creation he sees table of results based on data he provided. So I want to change it's direction to something more related to where Games keep their game saves - after that user should be navigated to file place in data storage.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I was referring to the Web bit, but I quoted part of your question talking about the Desktop bit. Sorry about that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.